# Selenium webdriver move mouse from one point to another

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to move the mouse from point A (random) to point B (an element) on the webpage using selenium and chrome driver.

As in simulating the mouse moving rather than just jumping from one point to another.

I have the coordinates of both the starting location and the destination element.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way of moving the cursor to a specific point, it seems my options are `MoveToElement` and `moveByOffset`. Both of which work with offsets so you can only move a certain distance from the element you are trying to click on.

**Moving the cursor**

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(element, offsetX, offsetY).Perform();
```

I'm using the code below to get the **starting location/coordinates** and the **current coordinates**

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("mousePosX =  0; mousePosY = 0; onmousemove = function(e){ mousePosX = e.clientX; mousePosY = e.clientY; console.log('Y:' + mousePosY + ' X:' + mousePosX); }; ");

IWebElement currentElement = driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
builder.MoveToElement(currentElement, randomStartX, randomStartY).Perform();

int mousePosX = convertJSMousePos(driver.ExecuteScript("return mousePosX;"));
int mousePosY = convertJSMousePos(driver.ExecuteScript("return mousePosY;"));
```

**Getting the destination coordinates**

```
IWebElement link = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("more info"));
System.Drawing.Point location = link.Location;

int targetXPostion = location.X;
int targetYPostion = location.Y;
```

I know the solution will be a loop that gradually reduces the offset until the X/Y target destination is reached or the destination element is in focus.

I feel like I have all the coordinates and methods I need but my attempts at slotting this all together have failed miserably so far.

Comment: I feel as though it may help some to know the reason that you are trying to simulate a real-mouse drag on the page. Is this testing some HTML5 game or interactive control?

Comment: As a workaround, you could calculate certain points between the starting and the target position, so that you can write your own method which would relocate the mouse in steps.